# How can I find the difference between queries that return multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, select, query, count

I have two tables, website and page, that look like such:

```
website
id | name
------------
1  | site 1
2  | site 2
3  | site 3

page
id | name | site_id |  deleted
----------------------------------
1  | home|    1     |     0
2  | pg2 |    1     |     1
3  | pg1 |    2     |     0
4  | pg2 |    2     |     0
5  | pg1 |    3     |     1
6  | this|    3     |     1
```

In the example, site 1 has one deleted page and one active page; site 2 has two active pages; site 3 has no active pages.  The goal is to return a list of websites that have no actives pages.

I have the following query that gives me the number of deleted pages for each site:

```
SELECT w.id, w.name, count(p.id) AS deleted_pages_num
FROM page p
RIGHT JOIN website w ON p.site_id = w.id
WHERE p.deleted = 1
GROUP BY p.site_id
```

Where you'd get this result

```
id| name   | deleted_pages_num
-------------------------------
1 | site 1 | 1
2 | site 2 | 0
3 | site 3 | 2
```

and vice versa where you'd set p.is_deleted = 0 to get the number of active pages each website has.  I need to find the difference between the two queries so that I can identify which sites have had all pages deleted.  Just totally blanking on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following:

```
select * from website a where not exists (select null from page where site_id=a.id and deleted=0)
```

Probably this is what you're asking for

Comment: EXISTS and NOT EXISTS! I can't remember the last time I used either.  Utterly and completely forgot about them.  Thank you, this did it.

Comment: Enjoy :-) and thank you for +15 of reputation :-D